# batch file renaming "This.is.a.FIlename.mp3" to "tiaf.mp3"

Tags: string, batch-file, filenames, extract, renaming

okay so I have a dir with some files. I want to do a specific file-renamingscript
i'm stuck with this part, taking only the first letter of each part of the filename:

if the filename would be

```
This.is.a.FIle.mp3
```

I would like to rename it to

```
tiaf.mp3
```

notice i want it to be all in lowercase.

The word length is variable so i cant take reference from it as a local variable !variable:~0,2!

anyone could help?
thanx!

edit: i forggot to ask. If you have an idea to make a test if the filename is of the format i mentioned. Because if the file is called. 'file.mp3' then i wouldn't want it to be renamed to 'f.mp3'

Comment: What OS and shell are you using?

Comment: i thought maybe i can extract the filename %%~n, put it in a variable,  and then I couls have to search each word witch has a dot after it (exccpt of the first part??) If i put these into variables I could call them with !variable:~0,1!    IS this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, but if you want to allow also "!" exclamation marks in your filenames, it have to be a little bit extended.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in ("C:\temp\folder\*.*") do (
    call :createName "%%~f"
)
goto :eof


:: Compress a filename with more than one dot to only the first (lower) letters of each part
:: one.TWO.three.four.exe to ottf.exe
:createName <dot-filename>
setlocal
set "filename=#.%~n1"
set "ext=%~x1"
set "count=0"
set "short="

:createName.loop
for %%a in ("!filename!") do (
    set "part=%%~xa"
    set "filename=%%~na"

    if defined part (
        set /a count+=1
        set "char=!part:~1,1!"
        call :toLower char
        set "short=!char!!short!"
    ) ELSE (
        set "char="
    )   
    rem echo "%%~na"-"%%~xa" "!char!"  "!short!"
)
if defined part goto :createName.loop
set "short=!short!!ext!"
if !count! GTR 1 (
    echo ren "%~f1" "!short!"
)
(
    endlocal
    goto :eof
)


:: convert a char to the lower variant or leave it unchanged if it isn't a char
:: use the %var:*n=% syntax to remove the front of a string, to get the correct char
:toLower <variable to char>
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
set "char=!%~1!"
set "helper=##aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz"
set "lower=!helper:*%char%=!"
set "lower=!lower:~0,1!"
if "!lower!"=="#" set "lower=!char!"
)
(
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%lower%"
    goto :eof
)
```

Comment: this is just what i needed!
Could you tel me where in the code i could call for a test? for number of filename parts. If it is only made of one part i wold like to call another function

Comment: It's at the if !count! GTR 1 ... part

Answer (score 3):

Would this kind of logic work for you:

```
@echo off

for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b C:\temp') do call :runsub %%f
goto EOF

:runsub
for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a in ("%~n1") do set a=%%a&set b=%%b&set c=%%c&set d=%%d

if not "%a%"=="" echo %a%
if not "%b%"=="" echo %b%
if not "%c%"=="" echo %c%
if not "%d%"=="" echo %d%

:EOF
```

You can change the echo %a%, echo %b%, etc. to sets and get the substring from these. This also only gets the first 4 splits, you can add more if you need. Also change C:\temp to the appropriate directory.

Comment: thanx, but i do get the echo opperation 2 times. so it printas all words but then does it again. Any idea where things go wrong? What does the "%a%"=="" test means?

Comment: I tried to add a 'e=%%e&set' but that gives me errors when the filename would consist of lesser parts then 5. ANy idea how to olve this?

Comment: the test %a%"=="" checks if the variable is blank before trying to use it in a command. Variables will be blank if the filename has less values separated by '.' than variables it's assigning to (i.e. if the filename is qwe.rty.mp3, than only variables %a% and %a% will have values and the other variables will be "" empty.

Comment: for e it look like this:  for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=." %%a in ("%~n1") do set a=%%a&set b=%%b&set c=%%c&set d=%%d&set e=%%e

Comment: The FOR-token has to be extended to FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims=." and therefore this solution is not very flexible